# wpf: change font size for WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, wpf, fonts, webbrowser-control

How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 public IHTMLDocument2 Document
 {
     get
     {
           return webBrowser.Document as IHTMLDocument2;
     }
 }
...
Document.execCommand("FontSize", false, doubleValue.ToString())
```

This shold help

Answer (score 3):

Right way for WPF:

> using mshtml; //reference to COM object "Microsoft HTML Object Library"
>
> ...
>
> var doc = web.Document as HTMLDocument; 
>   if (doc != null) 
>   {
>   doc.execCommand("SelectAll", false, null);
>   doc.execCommand("FontSize", false, 5);
>   doc.execCommand("Unselect", false, null);
>   }

additional information - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533049(VS.85).aspx

Comment: This won't work in Vista. Microsoft has removed support for MSHTML in Vista and above.