# Change font of html content converted to string using web browser control

Tags: c#, html, wpf, xaml

I am using [this](https://www.michelvandervlugt.net/wpf-document-binding-with-webbrowser-control/) to convert HTML content to XAML but I need to change font size of the content.  So, I am trying to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119055/wpf-change-font-size-for-webbrowser-control) to change the font size but I am getting `doc` as `null`. Any idea why?

Here's my code-

```
public static void DocumentPropertyChanged(DependencyObject target, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        WebBrowser browser = target as WebBrowser;

        var doc = browser.Document as HTMLDocument;

        if (browser != null)
        {
            string document = e.NewValue as string;
            browser.NavigateToString(document);
        }

        if (doc != null)
        {
            doc.execCommand("FontSize", false, 12);
            doc.execCommand("FontFamily", false, "Arial");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static void DocumentPropertyChanged(DependencyObject target, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!(target is WebBrowser)) // Handles null and other weird things.
        throw new Exception("target is not a WebBrowser!");

    WebBrowser browser = target as WebBrowser;

    string document = e.NewValue as string;

    if (document == null)
        throw new Exception("e.NewValue is not a string!");

    browser.NavigateToString(document);

    var doc = browser.Document as HTMLDocument;

    if (doc != null)
    {
        doc.execCommand("FontSize", false, 12);
        doc.execCommand("FontFamily", false, "Arial");
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception("browser.Document is not an HTMLDocument!");
    }
}
```

I *think* this requires a reference to Microsoft.mshtml.dll and a `using mshtml;` statement, if you haven't done that yet.

I've added all of the throws, because I'm not 100% confident where the problem is, having not run this code.

So for what it's worth, I hope this helps.

**Edit...**

The documentation states that `NavigateToString` loads the content ***asynchronously***.

By assigning `doc` *after* the navigation, the above code *appears* to work for very short documents, but that cannot be trusted. Assigning `doc` before navigation does not work.

A better solution might be to handle the `WebBrowser.Navigated` event to ensure the content has been fully loaded before interacting with the `WebBrowser.Document` property:

**XAML:**

```
<WebBrowser Name="browser" Navigated="Browser_Navigated"/>
```

**CS:**

```
public static void DocumentPropertyChanged(DependencyObject target, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    WebBrowser browser = target as WebBrowser;

    if (browser != null)
    {
        string document = e.NewValue as string;
        browser.NavigateToString(document);
    }
}

private void Browser_Navigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    var doc = webBrowser.Document as HTMLDocument;

    if (doc != null)
    {
        doc.execCommand("FontSize", false, 12);
        doc.execCommand("FontFamily", false, "Arial");
    }
}
```

Note: This code will run your `execCommand` (which I have not tested btw) on every document loaded into the `WebBrowser`. If this is a problem we can fix it.